# Kafka Message and Key both are appended with invalid characters when consuming in Java

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Message and Key both are appended with invalid characters and spaces.

1. Key is getting appended with spaces and ! (exclamation)
2. Message is getting appended with space and # (Hash)

Example, when I get the message in my project, this is the message.

```
Key:      !{"Person_ID":31724}

Message:        #{"Person_ID_KEY":"3172"}
```

This is happening all of a sudden. I have to skip the ! or # to get the proper message now and parse it. Do we know why this happens or any properties changes related to Spring Kafka or is it related towards the Kafka side?

Comment: What serializers are your producer using? How do you print the records?

Comment: In the Consumer end of my project, I am using StringDeserializer.  Using Kafka Connectors, we are loading message to the topic from a relational database. Using @KafkaListener to get the ConsumerRecord<String,String> message.

Comment: Okay, so in your Kafka Connector, are you using `StringConverter` or `JSONConverter`? If not, then you don't have string data that will be consumable using StringDeserializer

Comment: Control Center has Version 7.0.1 (d64510a). JDBCSourceConnector settings: 
Key Convertor Class : io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter
Value Convertor Class: io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter.

In my app, consumer config has StringDeserializer.class
props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> JDBCSourceConnector settings
>
> ```
> Key Converter Class : io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter  
> Value Converter Class : io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter
> ```

Then you are required to use `io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.KafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer` for your consumer properties as well as set `schema.registry.url`.

The reason you cannot use `StringDeserializer` is because it decodes UTF-8 data, and not the [Confluent Wire Format](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/index.html#wire-format).

---

Your other option is to use `JsonConverter` in your Connect properties from Apache package, **not** `JsonSchemaConverter` from Confluent.

Then, you may use `StringDeserializer`, or ideally [configure a JSON Consumer in Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#json-serde)

Comment: I was trying to make those changes but I got stuck on schema.registry.url. 
Any idea on how can I pass the  schema.registry.url in a spring boot application?

Comment: `props.put("schema.registry.url", "http://...")` in the consumer factory? Or in the Spring properties, set it on the `spring.kafka.consumer.properties`?

Comment: Yes. Im thinking we are having invalid registry url. Used all those configs and still getting Missing Required Configuration error for schema.registry.url. Once thats figured out, will mark this as solved. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: As mentioned, you don't really need the schema registry if you use the other JSONConverter for Connect that's built-in.

Comment: Working after we figured out proper schema url for our current environment. I used KafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer and set the schema registry as props.put("schema.registry.url", "http://...").  Thank you so much.

Comment: For higher env, I need to configure mTLS config. For the client end, I have access to truststore for higher regions. I have provided schema url as mentioned above. Do I also have to add SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG and other related configs to my consumer? I am getting ssl_handshake_exception as of now. If yes, who provides the keystore? I downloaded a pfx from Edge browser and changed it to jks and using it as keystore but getting a handshake exception.

Comment: JKS files should be created by `java keytool`  from the JDK and/or `openssl` commands, not downloaded from a browser, but yes, your consumer will need those, but the registry has its own HTTP Auth settings. https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/security/index.html